# Blue Card with provisional degree

Tags: germany, immigration, blue-card, indian-citizens

I will be applying for a blue card visa from India next month as I have got a job offer from Amazon Berlin. I have just recently graduated and my university has provided with a provisional degree certificate and an official transcript, I wanted to know will not having the original degree be an issue in my visa application?

I really don't have any option because universities here provide final degree certificate usually 1 year after graduating.

Comment: did you face any challenges? How was the process of immigration for you?